# Formatting a period of time

Tags: java, time, formatting

In Java I have a long integer representing a period of time in milliseconds. The time period could be anything from a couple of seconds to a number of weeks. I would like to output this time period as a String with the appropriate unit.

For example 3,000 should be output as "3 seconds", 61,200,000 should be output as "17 hours" and 1,814,400,000 should be output as "3 weeks".

Ideally I would also be able to fine-tune the formatting of sub-units, e.g. 62,580,000 might be output as "17 hours, 23 minutes".

Are there any existing Java classes that handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) library can do that for you:

```
PeriodFormatter yearsAndMonths = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
 .printZeroAlways()
 .appendYears()
 .appendSuffix(" year", " years")
 .appendSeparator(" and ")
 .printZeroRarely()
 .appendMonths()
 .appendSuffix(" month", " months")
 .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 7):

See also [DurationFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html) in the Apache commons.

Answer (score 0):

Check out joda-time's [format package](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Something like this works good too         
        long period = ...;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.insert(0, String.valueOf(period % MILLISECS_IN_SEC) + "%20milliseconds");
        if (period > MILLISECS_IN_SEC - 1)
            sb.insert(0, String.valueOf(period % MILLISECS_IN_MIN / MILLISECS_IN_SEC) + "%20seconds,%20");
        if (period > MILLISECS_IN_MIN - 1)
            sb.insert(0, String.valueOf(period % MILLISECS_IN_HOUR / MILLISECS_IN_MIN) + "%20minutes,%20");
        if (period > MILLISECS_IN_HOUR - 1)
            sb.insert(0, String.valueOf(period % MILLISECS_IN_DAY / MILLISECS_IN_HOUR) + "%20hours,%20");
        if (period > MILLISECS_IN_DAY - 1)
            sb.insert(0, String.valueOf(period / MILLISECS_IN_DAY) + "%20days,%20");

        return sb.toString();
```

Comment: That is an ugly way to do it.